# Will sybpydb work with Sybase ASE 15.0?

Tags: python, sybase, sap-ase

I got sybpydb (Sybase Python extension module) from a Sybase ASE 15.7 installation. 
But most other servers in our team are still in 15.0.
Can I develop Python scripts with sybpydb to access those 15.0 servers?

I got this error and am not sure if this is simply because sybpydb won't work with an old ASE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sybpydb.DatabaseError: Error in connecting to the server.
```

Comment: I just found the answer by myself. But here is another question. How can I copy sybpydb from a 15.7 server to other place (without using root/sybase account)? I tar'ed the whole OCS folder, but it didn't work. Is there other better way?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was from interfaces. After an update, everything works fine with 15.0.3 ASE servers.

So the answer is yes, sybpydb from Sybase ASE 15.7 works with 15.0 servers.

```
ops@:~$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 22 2011, 10:50:25) [C] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sybpydb
>>> conn = sybpydb.connect(user='xxx', password='xxx', servername='xxx')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select top 1 * from ant_absence")
>>> rows = cur.fetchall()
>>> print rows
[(10000890, '0129119', 'E', 'PM', 1388480143)]
>>> cur.execute("select @@version")
>>> rows = cur.fetchall()
>>> print rows
[('Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3/EBF 17779 ESD#4/P/Solaris AMD64/OS 5.10/ase1503/2768/64-bit/FBO/Thu Aug 26 11:42:38 2010',)]
```